# Synchronous submit not firing outside IE

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a pretty simple form that I'm trying to post back synchronously to the server. In IE, everything works fine. Hit submit, it goes to the server, everything's golden. Any other browser (well, I tried Chrome, FF and Opera) just sits there when I hit the submit button. Put it in an UpdatePanel, and everything fires fine. I suppose I can just go with the UpdatePanel and do it asynchronously--it certainly wouldn't hurt--but I'd at least like to know what is going wrong.

EDIT: I'm not sure what might be gained from the HTML--it's pretty straightforward form + submit button, but here it is:

```
<div id="leftColumn">

    <formContent />

</div>

<div id="rightColumn">

    <conditionalFormContent />
</div>

<div class="clear">

    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$SubmitButton" value="Send Report" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$SubmitButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_SubmitButton" />

</div>
```

Ah, perhaps you meant the ASP code?

```
<asp:Button runat="server" 
                ID="SubmitButton"
                Text="Send Report" 
                OnClick="SubmitReport"
                UseSubmitBehavior="true" 
                CausesValidation="true" />
```

Comment: please add you aspx and cs code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `UseSubmitBehavior` to false on the button.

Comment: That did it, thanks. That's weird--I had assumed that UseSubmitBehavior would simply determine whether it was an input type="submit" or input type="button" (which it does do, apparently), but I didn't think it would do more. That's what I get for not reading the documentation.